# Adding an brace at the right of equation numbering

Tags: equations

I use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:solve}
x^2 - 5 x + 6 = 0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x_1 = \frac{5 + \sqrt{25 - 4 \times 6}}{2} = 3
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x_2 = \frac{5 - \sqrt{25 - 4 \times 6}}{2} = 2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

to display:

[image]

How can I add an brace with a text on the right of the equation numbering? Like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is one way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{drcases*}
\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:solve}
x^2 - 5 x + 6 = 0
\end{equation}    
\begin{equation}
x_1 = \frac{5 + \sqrt{25 - 4 \times 6}}{2} = 3
\end{equation}
% don't leave blank line    
\begin{equation}
x_2 = \frac{5 - \sqrt{25 - 4 \times 6}}{2} = 2
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\end{drcases*}
\text{bla bla bla}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]